# Signing AWS API request with payload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hash, signing, amazon-mws

While trying to connect to the new [Selling Partner API](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-4-create-and-sign-your-request) for Amazon, I'm trying to use the following [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-post) to sign my request properly:

```
import hashlib
import json
payload = {
    "reportType": "GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA",
    "dataStartTime": "2020-10-10T20:11:24.000Z",
    "marketplaceIds": [
        "A1PA6795UKMFR9"
    ]
}

payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

returns the `payload_hash` of `942a2ee7d7dd8727860f6da72dd33c6620bc5af2633730bb7bd711745b16d30e` to me.
When I append this to the request as described and send it to the Sellingpartner API the response tells that the payload hash should have been `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`.

What am I doing wrong?

A full example of the code can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jugi92/bf0f5e7f52dbb52bfca73f0ffbff5e6a).

Comment: https://github.com/python-amazon-mws/python-amazon-mws looks promising at first glance

Comment: unfortunately it is using the mws API, not the new Selling Partner Api recently introduced

Comment: Ah,  right.   In that case I'd suggest you supply a complete,  minimal,  verifiable example so we can see the full picture of what you're doing

Comment: I added a link to the gist with the full code

Answer (score 2):

There is a colon missing on one of those lines.  I still don't have it working, but it moved me on to the next error...

On Line 125
'x-amz-content-sha256' + payload_hash
should be
'x-amz-content-sha256:' + payload_hash

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32616185)